# Changing pre-trained model's parameters

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, pre-trained-model

I need to change parameters of a pre-trained model, not in any particular way. I'm trying this:

```py
ids = [int(p.sum().item()) for p in model.parameters()]
print(ids[0])

for i in model.parameters():
    x = i.data
    x = x/100

    break;

ids = [int(p.sum().item()) for p in model.parameters()]
print(ids[0])
```

but it outputs two exactly the same numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple: you need to perform an in-place operation, otherwise you'll operate on a new object:

```py
for i in model.parameters():
    x = i.data
    x /= 100
    break
```

Here's a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```py
import torch

torch.manual_seed(2021)

m = torch.nn.Linear(1, 1)

# show current value of the weight
print(next(m.parameters()))
# > tensor([[-0.7391]], requires_grad=True)

for i in m.parameters():
    x = i.data
    x = x/100
    break

# same value :(
print(next(m.parameters()))
# > tensor([[-0.7391]], requires_grad=True)

for i in m.parameters():
    x = i.data
    x /= 100
    break

# now, we changed it
print(next(m.parameters()))
# > tensor([[-0.0074]], requires_grad=True)
```

P.S.: `break` is unnecessary in my example, but I kept it just because you used it in your example.

Comment: Thanks for this. How come altering ```x``` (which is ```i```'s data) affects ```i``` itself, do they share the same memory? And why wouldn't ```i /=100``` work?

Comment: @OmarAlSuwaidi yes, they are all basically pointing to the same [Storage](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/storage.html). You can't operate directly in `i`, in this case, because it is a leaf variable that requires grad, and in-place ops are not allowed for this type of variable.